# React Native components seem to be sharing a state

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue with React-native where I have a component `TouchTimer` which uses an [AnimatedTimer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-timer) component. This timer is supposed to start and stop when it is tapped, which it does, however all of the TouchTimer components I add to a page will start and stop whenever any of them are tapped, rather than only affecting the tapped component.

Below is a snippet of my component:

#### TouchTimer.tsx

```
export class TouchTimer extends React.Component<TouchTimerProps> {
  state: {
    ...
    paused: boolean,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.state = {
      ...
      paused: true,
    }
  }

  startStop() {
    this.setState({paused: !this.state.paused});
  }

  render() {
    const { time } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.startStop()}>
        <View>
          <AnimatedTimer
            ...
            time={time}
            pause={this.state.paused}
          />
          <View style={styles.timeContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.time}>{this.state.remaining}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is a snippet of the screen containing these components:

#### Details.tsx

```
import { TouchTimer } from '../components/TouchTimer';
...
export class RecipeDetailsScreen extends React.Component<NavigationInjectedProps> {
...
  {this.state.steps.map(step => (
    <List.Item
      key={step.id}
      title={"Step " + step.index}
      style={styles.step}
      description={step.short_desc}
      right={() => (step.time > 0 &&
        <TouchTimer
          time={step.time * 60000}
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

I have tried wrapping the `TouchTimer` components in a `View` and changing the `paused` boolean to a prop, to no avail.

I have also tested to see if this issue appears when the components are not siblings, and when they are not produced as the result of a callback, and the issue still persists in both these cases.

If anybody has any advice or answers on how to make these timers independent I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Curiously that component seems to be implemented with a global `pauseFlag` that applies to all component instances. See https://github.com/dalisalvador/react-native-animated-timer/blob/master/src/Components/AnimatedTimer.js#L34

So I don't think you're doing anything wrong here, this is a limitation of the library code that is coupling all instances of your timer to the same `pauseFlag` value.

Comment: Oh that's frustrating! Do you have any suggestions how to modify the component or use a different approach to achieve a similar result?